# Is there a suiting percentage symbol (%) when using eulervm? Or can we fake one?

Tags: fonts, symbols, eulervm

Seems that when using the `eulervm` package the % symbol is taken from computer modern. I find this a bit suprising and not so suiting. The percentage symbol is really thin...

Does anyone know of some good looking alternatives to this? At least I don't think I have missed any library parameters for it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\begin{document}
$40\%$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Edit: Perhaps something can be built using the 0 symbol from Euler and if so can such a build be made to be used automagicly for %-symbol in math mode?

Comment: I'm afraid the Euler fonts don't have a suiting percent sign.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `xelatex` or `lualatex` and the *new* Euler font from https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf/blob/master/euler.otf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Neo Euler}
\begin{document}
40\%
\end{document}
```

and also for math:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont{Neo Euler}
\setmathfont[range={\mathit->\mathup}]{Neo Euler}% Euler has no italic
\begin{document}
$40\% foo$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but won't this mean sacrificing a lot of math specific benefits that comes with the `eulervm` package? I am thinking of Euler version of sum symbols and such things.

Comment: why should it??

Comment: Well put. So a package is not needed to mess with such things? I guess I will have to try it out and stop worrying :)

Comment: The font has a very nice looking % symbol, sadly though it does not seem to do letters at all. My formulas now lost all letters... :(

Comment: see my edited answer for math. It should help. if not give an example of what you did

Comment: Yea the `\mathit->\mathup` did the trick.

Comment: @Herbert -- your edited code may work, but you didn't change the image to use it.  (i haven't tried it, but assume that since jonalv says it works, it really does.)

Answer (score 7):

You could grow your own, using the `0` glyphs from `eulervm`.  You can tweak the numbers to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\pct{\vstretch{.8}{\stackengine{1ex}%
  {$\stretchrel*{/}{\%}\kern-3pt\scriptscriptstyle0$}
  {$\kern-.6pt\scriptscriptstyle0$}{O}{l}{F}{F}{L}}}
$40\pct$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, is it possible to get this `\pct` macro to be called automagicly for % symbol in math mode so one don't have to remember to write `\pct`?

Comment: @jonalv ``\DeclareRobustCommand{\%}{\ifmmode\pct\else\char`\% \fi}``